# "Create List" function in Excel automation C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, automation

i am looking to create a drop-down list of items in excel through automation in C#, the items are taken from the values in the whole column throughout the file. The same functionality of right click on a cell and click "Create List"

I looked a bit through the internets but nothing works, i saw you could do this via Data validation, but can't find too much information about it

thx for any help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these links might help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/cc337988.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268997.aspx